How to achieve account linking in Google smart home action?
I have done the setup for OAuth 2.0 Client ID setup in the Google Cloud Console and got the client id and secret key.
The Auth endpoint is also available at https://web.vetaar-anchor.com/#/ActionAuth address.
The Auth endpoint basically is the Angular project.
In the account linking section of the respective action all the information such as
*client id
*secret
*auth endpoint (https://web.vetaar-anchor.com/#/ActionAuth)
*Token Endpoint
is properly set up.
But when I am tapping on a [TEST] 
I am supposed to get https://web.vetaar-anchor.com/#/ActionAuth?client_id=GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&state=STATE_STRING&scope=REQUESTED_SCOPES&response_type=code&user_locale=LOCALE
But I am only getting https://web.vetaar-anchor.com/#/ActionAuth
How Am i supposed to get the url parameters?
AM  not doing something correctly?
I tried doing account linking correctly and filled all the necessary information in the account linking section.
Also I created the OAuth 2.0 credentials such as client id and secret.
I am expecting URL parameters in the Auth endpoint when I tap on the Action in the Google Home App but I am only getting the Auth url without required url parameters for code generation.

I am still looking for a solution.
Any help would be appreciated.
